# Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub

Tags: r, github, ggplot2, installation, failed-installation

I am trying to install the ggpattern package from GitHub (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggpattern/versions/0.2.0)

I've reinstalled R, followed the all steps according to the site, also tried

`remotes::install_github("coolbutuseless/ggpattern", force = TRUE)`

But I still get:

```
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
  HTTP error 401.
  Bad credentials

  Rate limit remaining: 19/60
  Rate limit reset at: 2022-01-29 18:28:15 UTC
```

I'm working on R version 4.1.2 (newest according to me) on Windows.
Do you have any idea what is the issue here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to check if you have a personal access token set in your environment. For example, when I have a Git project, I set a personal access token. However, I set this in the project environment, so that it isn't any issues outside of that environment.

To see if there is one assigned:

```
Sys.getenv("GITHUB_PAT")
```

If there is one set, write it down (you may need that in the future).

To remove it, so you can install the GitHub package:

```
Sys.unsetenv("GITHUB_PAT")
```

Comment: Thank you so so much, that has actually worked!

Comment: Just to add - `Sys.setenv(GITHUB_PAT = "your PAT")` is necessary if you have a PAT from Github already.